# Duplicate values saved when using scanner. next()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to capture the filename here. I am testing it with giving incorrect values first. I am getting multiple lines of "Just before returning" when I give the right value starting from the latest one(right path) to the oldest(incorrect path). How is it looped in that `Sysout` statement. How can I resolve this?

```
static String setFilePath(){

    String filepath = null;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {               
        System.out.println("enter the file path");
        filepath = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You have entered :"+filepath);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (filepath));



    } 
    catch (InputMismatchException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a proper FilePath");
            //in.next(); // Read and discard whatever string the user has entered
            ex.printStackTrace();
            setFilePath();

    }
    keyboard.close();
    System.out.println("Just before returning :"+filepath);
    return filepath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a recursive statement here in the `catch`:

```
catch (InputMismatchException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a proper FilePath");
      //in.next(); // Read and discard whatever string the user has entered
      ex.printStackTrace();
      setFilePath(); //Right here
}
```

So once you finally stop the recursion all the calls on the stack will resolve and all the print statements will execute. To fix this you want to return the results of the method so that the results of the methods on the stack will exit without printing.

```
return setFilePath();
```

Also it is bad practice to close a `System.in`. The general rule is that if you did not open a resource, you should not close it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!
I had a similar piece of code without the return and recursion in the catch that just worked fine. Why would that be. Should I be adding return there as well regardless?

Comment: @Seb Without the `return` statements your code will return where it was called and execute the print statements, and you will have essentially thrown away the results of the method call. With the `return` statements the methods exit the method and do not execute the print statements